# How to reverse engineer this router firmware using binwalk?

Tags: firmware, router

I want to modify router firmware so I can enable telnet. What steps should I take? The router is hg630v2; the firmware can be found at [this link](https://www.upload-4ever.com/p5ewx5egqigk). It's Linux based.

When I do

```
binwalk --signature --term HG630V2-12V100R001C36B023_multicast_restore_default_pack.bin
```

it gives this output:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
307           0x133           LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xB7, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 808333686 bytes
12909         0x326D          LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 121464 bytes
198089        0x305C9         Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:xz, size: 6088994 bytes, 1254 inodes, blocksize: 1048576 bytes, created:
                              2017-03-14 13:21:06
6288841       0x5FF5C9        uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0xCE31434, created: 2017-03-14 13:20:27, image size: 1426862 bytes, Data Address:
                              0x81208000, Entry Point: 0x81208000, data CRC: 0xE377A30F, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma,
                              image name: "Linux-2.6.30"
6288905       0x5FF609        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 3823840 bytes
```

I want to able to repack the router after extraction and fix CRC issue to be uploaded and installed.

Comment: Have you ruled out that it can't be enabled by another means such as downloading a config backup, modifying a parameter and restoring?  Or whether there are any hidden fields in requests to the web interface that could be modified?  Or was there a specific reason you wanted to do it by modifying the firmware?

Comment: i tried decrypt backup file i successfully decrypt it but i don't see option for enable telnet i gain access to telnet and ssh but when i tried to write any command it says command failed and when i login it give me a message Server refused to allocate pty